# XCode: Unable to embed a UITableview in a UIViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, swift2, xcode7

I want to create a UIViewController with an embedded UITableView. I've seen various examples but so far have been unable to get it to work. The outlets are embedded in the table cells.

```
class CREWStartMenuVCCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var myTextView: UITextView!
}

class CREWStartMenuVC: UIViewController { // , UITableViewDelegate { // UITableViewDataSource,

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!  //<<-- TableView Outlet

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    createAppData()

    tableView.registerClass(CREWStartMenuVCCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: getCellName(viewName))
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CREWStartMenuVCCell! {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(getCellName(viewName), forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CREWStartMenuVCCell
```

// processing cell code not relevant

I get this error if I attempt to override the following functions: Method does not override any method from its superclass. What am I missing?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat { // was override
    // calculate length of text and adjust the size of cell for that

        return calculateTipsHeight(viewName, text:getTipsInfo(viewName, sectionNumber: indexPath.section, tipOrder: indexPath.row).tipItemText)
    }

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {section))
    return getTipsRowCount (viewName, sectionNumber: 0)
}
```

### UPDATE

I get the following errors when I try to add UITableViewDataSource:

```
5:17: Protocol requires function 'tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)' with type '(UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell'

34:10: Candidate has non-matching type '(UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CREWStartMenuVCCell!'
```

I don't see the error.

Comment: Implement CellForRowAtIndexPath, numberOfRowsInSections in your class with tableDataSource &TablleDelegate. as follows

class CREWStartMenuVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource,

Comment: If I alter the class as you suggested (I tried this before) I get this message: type 'CREWStartMenuVC' does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'

Answer (score 2):

Since the class CREWStartMenuVC does NOT inherit from UITableViewController (or any other class which implements those methods), the methods in the protocols UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource can (or must) be implemented but they are not overridden. That means that the implementation of those methods cannot be preceded by

```
override
```

Also, in case you didn't do it in the Storyboard, don't forget to set the delegate and the dataSource of the tableView, for example, in the call to viewDidLoad() of your CREWStartMenuVC class.

```
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
```

About the two errors from the UPDATE, just replace

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CREWStartMenuVCCell!
```

with

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CREWStartMenuVCCell!
```

(the only differences are the exclamations ! after the classes UITableView and NSIndexPath)

Comment: I had tried adding this before but I still couldn't override the functions.

Comment: See the edited answer. As I said, you don't have to use the command override

Comment: I had tried without the override but it makes no difference. When I run the view it displays the items before the tableview but nothing else.

Comment: I don't know. What I'm pretty sure about is that the phrase _Method does not override any method from its superclass_ means that you trying to `override` some method that is not implemented by the superclass.

Comment: Obviously I did but how do I get the method to get invoked? and why can't I use UITableViewDataSource?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure I understand the last questions. You can use UITableViewDataSource for sure. And to declare the method it would just be 
`func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat { 
        return calculateTipsHeight(viewName, text:getTipsInfo(viewName, sectionNumber: indexPath.section, tipOrder: indexPath.row).tipItemText)
    }`

Comment: I've updated my question to show details about my problem. I had not seen the entire message before.

Comment: See the updated answer. Sorry I didn't realise sooner

Comment: I have managed to get rid of the error regarding UITableViewDataSource but I do not know how to reference myButton and myTextView without referencing my custom cell code ... but I'll see if I can figure out how to do that.

Comment: I'm glad to help if I can but if you have a different question, it seems appropriate to ask a different question. Also, if the answer I gave you was of any help, I'd really appreciate if you could select it as the correct answer or upvote it (since I need reputation to be able to comment everywhere).

Comment: I'd like to give you credit for your help but I'm still going around in circles ... I fixed the UITableViewDataSource error but then I get error that there are no members for my textview and buttons in uitableviewcell. Can you suggest how I can access them?

Comment: Let's see. Could you actually pase the message of error you get? If the message is exactly `There are no members for myTextView in UITableViewCell`, that means that you're trying to access those properties in an instance of the class `UITableViewCell`. If you're sure that it is actually an instance of your custom class `CREWStartMenuVCCell`, then you can force the downcast with `as! CREWStartMenuVCCell`(as you have done in the question)

Comment: As you will see below I managed to get it to work, although I seem to have a conceptual problem with not being able to scroll the table. But that is a different problem which I will not trouble you with.

Comment: (I cannot comment  below because I've not enough reputation). I don't think that a solution. If you don't set your controller as the tableView's dataSource, the code in  `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` won't get called for your tableView. So yes, it seems to work (maybe the problem was caused by the `registerClass` method), but that does not solve your issue (I believe)

Comment: Ultimately I decided that this was the wrong approach and instead used a UITableViewController and added the image (which I was trying to insert at the top of the view) to the table view row header.

Comment: Seems like the sensible thing to do ;)

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work without UITableViewDataSource after I removed the tableView.registerClass
Here is the working code:

```
class CREWStartMenuVCCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var myTextView: UITextView!
}


class CREWStartMenuVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate { //,  UITableViewDataSource { //

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!  //<<-- TableView Outlet

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    createAppData()

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CREWStartMenuVCCell {
        let cell  = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(getCellName(viewName), forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CREWStartMenuVCCell

        // MARK: Common tips code
```